# What does this mean? Is it an if else representation?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

What does the following mean?

```
    var iCurrentIndex = oCurrentQuestionModel.getProperty("/index"); ...(1)
    iCurrentIndex = iCurrentIndex ? ++iCurrentIndex : 0; ...(2)
```

The var iCurrentIndex = false in setp 1 and in step 2 it gets assigned value 0.
What does this representation mean can anyone explain me?

Comment: It's a ternary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @Jeremy Jackson Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your step 2 can be rewritten like this:

```
if (iCurrentIndex) {
    ++iCurrentIndex;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

You are using *ternary* operator, read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Thank you the link was useful but why would someone use a ternary operator instead of if and else? just curious

Comment: If you have a short conditional sometimes it's ok to put it on one line instead of 5 :)

Comment: @loki It's just a matter of personal preference, readability or shorter code...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
var iCurrentIndex = oCurrentQuestionModel.getProperty("/index");
```

returns an `undefined` or `null` or just `false`, then an increment can not take place.

Then you need a check if the returned value is truthy (a value which resolves to `true`, if casted to boolean), then just increment or assign zero to `iCurrentIndex`.

```
iCurrentIndex = iCurrentIndex ? ++iCurrentIndex : 0;
```

The above [conditional oparator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) uses a condition and evaluates either the part after `?`, the *then* part of an `if` statement or the part after `:`, the `else` part of an `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you. So is ternary operator preferred more over if else statements?

Comment: @loki, actually, you make an increment **and** an assignment so it is not really a good example of using a conditional operator.